# `toPrecision` and literals

Tags: javascript

So I just found this:

```js
let number = -1234;
console.log(number.toPrecision(3)); // -1.23e+3
console.log(-1234..toPrecision(3)); // -1230
```

Can anyone explain what exactly is going on? The only thing I can think of is that in the second case the optimiser pre-calculates the expression, and that the optimiser's implementation of `toPrecision` is different from the compiler's.

Tested on:

- Safari/Mac, Version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34)
- Chrome/Mac, Version 59.0.3071.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Firefox/Mac, 54.0.1 (64-bit)

EDIT: Re: being triggered by the decimal point, great observation - however, if we add the decimal point into `number`, it doesn't suddenly de-exponentise:

```js
let number = -1234.5;
console.log(number.toPrecision(3));  // -1.23e+3
console.log(-1234.5.toPrecision(3)); // -1230
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem related to operator precedence.

With parenthesis added, your expression will be like:

```
(-1234).toPrecision(3)  // "-1.23e+3"
-(1234..toPrecision(3)) // -1230
```

`1234..toPrecision(3)` is first calculated, which is `"1.23e+3"`.
Then the expression becomes `-"1.23e+3"`, which is `-1230`.

Comment: In other words: String vs number

Comment: Thank you, I suspected I was missing something obvious!

Comment: This answer can be verified using `typeof`. The first produces `string`, the second produces `number`.